# How can I share build config between two build.gradle.kts files?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have two projects (in a single git repository) that should have the same

```
repository {

}
```

section in their `build.gradle.kts`, but otherwise are completely unrelated.

Can I factor this common part out and include it in each respective  `build.gradle.kts`? How?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update** In the [`0.11.0`](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/releases/tag/v0.11.1) release, `applyFrom(uri)` was removed.

You should now instead use:

```
apply {
    from("dir/myfile.gradle")
}
```

---

**Old answer**

With Groovy build scripts you can do something like `apply from: 'dir/myfile.gradle'` where `dir/myfile.gradle` is a file containing your shared `repositories` block.

In a similar fashion with [Gradle Script Kotlin](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/org/gradle/script/lang/kotlin/ProjectExtensions.kt#L61) (at least with `0.4.1`), you can use the `applyFrom(script: Any)` method.

**build.gradle.kts**

```
applyFrom("dir/myfile.gradle")
```

If you need to apply it from a subproject you could do something like:

```
applyFrom("${rootProject.rootDir}/dir/myfile.gradle")
```

Answer (score 2):

No idea if it works with kotlin however you can try equivalent from plain gradle:

**lol.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply from: 'lol.gradle'
```

Above works fine. Mind that *lol.gradle* has `java` plugin applied - it adds context where `repositories` is present hence can be applied.

Answer (score 1):

We use an [init script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:init_script_plugins) bundled in a custom gradle distribution to apply our corporate Nexus repository to every gradle project. It's worth considering if you have a lot of projects.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem when common config is replicated in each and every project. Solved it by a custom gradle distribution with the common settings defined in init script.

Created a gradle plugin for preparing such custom distributions - [custom-gradle-dist](http://gradle-dist.oss.harmonysoft.tech/). It works perfectly for my projects, e.g. a *build.gradle* for a library project looks like this (this is a complete file, all *repository*, *plugin*, common *dependencies* etc are defined in the custom init script):

```groove
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
}
```